# What will be the optimized and fast way to generate 1 million random points in Python?

Tags: python, performance, random

Basically I need over a million points on x-y plane. I am thinking about first generating 1 million points in range -x to x, another million in range y to -y and then coupling them together. What will be optimized and fast way to do this? In random.randrange good enough?

Comment: Say hello to [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/)

Comment: Are you sure this is a bottleneck? Creating 1,000,000 points with `random.randint` for x and y, takes 5 seconds on my machine. EDIT: And 600 milliseconds using `random.random` multiplying it with a factor...

Comment: Same for me as Hyperboreus. One speed up could be to make your coordinate generator...a generator. Yield random points as you need them instead of preallocating so many.

Comment: @BlakeVandeMerwe I need them together. I have to perform voronoi tessellation on these points.

Comment: If you want to tesselate them later, I strongly doubt that 600 milliseconds (or 44 ms with NPS's answer) are really an issue.

Comment: Do they have to be unique?

Answer (score 1):

I would use NumPy for that. In my quick test `numpy.random.uniform()` is over 60 times faster than calling `random.randrange()` in a loop.

```
In [12]: %timeit [random.randrange(-10, 10) for _ in range(2000000)]
1 loops, best of 3: 2.95 s per loop

In [13]: %timeit numpy.random.uniform(-10, 10, (1000000, 2))
10 loops, best of 3: 43.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: Replace `randrange` with `random` and do your multiplication and substraction as with numpy, and the difference will be quite different. You are basically comparing pears with apples.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: I find your argument hard to follow. Please show the exact code that you have in mind.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Your argument was about performance. The difference in performance between the original and the edited answer is very small compared to the difference between pure Python and NumPy. The edit was mainly done for reasons of style.